# Accidently creating gigantic file with write

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

this is the code I am using:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 void main(){
  test = creat("TEST",0751);
  close(test);
  test = open("TEST",2);
  write(test, "123456789101112131415",21);
  lseek(test,-2,2);
  read(test,swap_array,2);
  write(test,swap_array,2);
  lseek(test,-6, 1);
  write(test,"xx",2);
 }
```

This creates an 8gb file containing instead of inserting "xx" in between the numbers as I intend. What is wrong with the code as I have it?

Comment: Since you don't show your `#include`s, we can't know what prototypes are in scope. Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are having.  See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Use constants instead of the magic numbers! Why do we need to translate them into anything meaningful?

Answer (score 3):

You have failed to include the appropriate header files. You should include, at a minimum:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Additionally, this will give you access to the symbolic constants required to make your code maintainable.

Here is a working version of your program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
 char swap_array[2];
 int test = creat("TEST",0751);
 close(test);
 test = open("TEST",O_RDWR);
 write(test, "123456789101112131415",21);
 lseek(test,-2,SEEK_END);
 read(test,swap_array,2);
 write(test,swap_array,2);
 lseek(test,-6, SEEK_CUR);
 write(test,"xx",2);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The headers solve the issue. And the flags I copy-pasted strictly for the example.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  The canonical flags for `creat()` — or the third argument of `open()` — are direly verbose: [`S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) for `0751`.  It's a lot easier to read the octal than the standardese.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could live with `#define MODE_0751 (S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH)`; that keeps both parties relatively happy.  :)

Comment: Note that modern POSIX (2004, 2008/2013) does not require `<sys/types.h>`.  The code shown doesn't seem to use anything from `<sys/stat.h>` either AFAICS, though if you go for the symbolic permissions, that's where they're found.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler. I don't have POSIX handy, so I relied upon Linux man pages. `man lseek` lists `<sys/types.h>`, and `man 2 open` lists `<sys/stat.h>`.

Comment: The headers fcntl.h and says/stat.h have a complex inter-relation.   The sys/types.h was once important, but it is almost accurate to say "in another millennium".

Answer (score 3):

You probably aren't including the headers, so there's probably no prototype for `lseek()` in scope, so the `2` in the middle argument is an `int`, but `lseek()` expects (<s>a `long`</s>) an `off_t`, and you're on a 64-bit machine where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long)` so the two `2`'s are misinterpreted by the system call (maybe treating them as the offset and for whatever reason what's left on the stack is interpreted as `SEEK_SET` or otherwise jumps to a large offset).

Basically, you're probably passing inaccurately typed information to the system call because you haven't included the correct headers.  Classically (before POSIX interfered), the middle `2` would be `2L` because the `l` in `lseek()` stood for 'long' — prior to that, there was a `seek()` which took a plain `int` (in the days of 16-bit `int` types) — to ensure that a `long` is passed as [`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html)
requires.  These days, `lseek()` requires an `off_t`; using the prototype is crucial to ensure that what you write is interpreted correctly as an `off_t`.

There's a lot of UB lurking in that description, but the fact that you're not using `SEEK_SET` etc raises warning flags.  Also, why is the file executable?  That doesn't look like executable code you're writing.

This variant of the code is more careful (and doesn't create an 8 GiB file on Mac OS X 10.11.6 with GCC 6.2.0).

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MODE_0751 (S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH)

int main(void)
{
    // All error checking omitted
    char swap_array[2];
    int test = creat("TEST", MODE_0751);
    close(test);
    test = open("TEST", O_RDWR);
    write(test, "123456789101112131415", 21);
    lseek(test, -2L, SEEK_END);
    read(test, swap_array, 2);
    write(test, swap_array, 2);
    lseek(test, -6L, SEEK_CUR);
    write(test, "xx", 2);
    close(test);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the `L`'s out of (very) old habit, but they're optional.  The various 2's could be replaced by `sizeof(swap_array)` (and `sizeof("xx")-1`).  I learned C long enough ago that the octal permissions were the only way of doing business; the `S_IRWXU` and related names were years in the future.  I find a 4-digit or 5-digit octal number more readable than a string of `S_Iwxyz` names.

Make sure you compile your code with options set so that prototypes are required before you can use functions.  For example, I use:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition mx19.c -o mx19
$
```

Comment: 'so the two 2's are treated...' I doubt: both AMD and MS ABI would use registers to pass first 4 arguments on x64.

Comment: @Serge maybe it's i386.

Comment: Technically the second argument to `lseek()` is `off_t`, not `int` or `long`.

Comment: @FUZxxl still, the original statement misleading.

Comment: That does not excuse the lack of headers, e.t.c., of course